# how to update the field in database when button is click in yii2?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

what i want is when i click the "right" button my content in field "status" in database table is update from null to "approve". and when i click button "x" the  content in field "status" in database table is update from null to "reject".

```
'buttons' => [

                    'view' => function ($url, $model){
                        return Html::a('<span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', $url, [
                                        'title' => Yii::t('app','view'),
                                        ]);
                    },
                    'approve' => function ($url, $model){
                        return Html::a('<span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>', $url, [
                                        'title' => Yii::t('app','approve'),
                                        ]);
                    },
                    'reject' => function ($url, $model){
                        return Html::a('<span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>', $url, [
                                        'title' => Yii::t('app','reject'),
                                        ]);
                    }
        ],

        'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                if ($action === 'view') {
                    $url = 'index.php?r=appointment-confirmation/view&id='.$model->appID;
                    return $url;
                }
                if ($action === 'approve') {
                    $url = 'index.php?r=appointment-confirmation/view&id='.$model->appID;
                    return $url;
                }
                if ($action === 'reject') {
                    $url = 'index.php?r=appointment-confirmation/view&id='.$model->appID;
                    return $url;
                }   
        }
```

so this is what its look like:[image]

Comment: Create Two action Approve and Reject or Create ChangeStatus action and pass status respected for approval and rejection.

Comment: you never add your part of attempt to solve the problem, looking at your previous posts it looks habitual, you should start the work atleast and then ask here when you get stucked at any point

Answer (score 0):

Create links to changeStatus action, pass status as get-parameter:

```
if ($action === 'approve') {
    return $url = Url::to(['appointment-confirmation/change-status', 'id' => $model->appID, 'status' => 'approve']);
}
if ($action === 'reject') {
    return $url = Url::to(['appointment-confirmation/change-status', 'id' => $model->appID, 'status' => 'reject']);
}
```

Create action changeStatus (find appointment, change status, redirect to view):

```
public function actionChangeStatus($id, $status)
{
    $appointment = Appointment::findOne($id);
    if (!$appointment) {
        throw new HttpException(404);
    }
    $appointment->status = $status;
    if ($appointment->save()) {
        $this->redirect(['view', $id => $appointment->id]);
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Error while saving appointment');
    }
}
```